# Use tf.shape(tensor) as a bound for a loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensor

Using Tensorflow in Python, I want to use the shape of a placeholder for the bound of a for-loop. However, when I try to do this, I get the error: 'Tensor' object cannot be interpreted as an integer. This shape is not a constant value across the data so we cannot use a tf.constant. How can we solve this problem?

Here is a part of our code:

```
def Model(M, v_a, weights, biases, d, N):

c = multilayer_perceptron((tf.slice(M, [0, 0], ([d, 1]))), v_a, weights, 
    biases)

for i in range(1, N):

    c = tf.concat([c, multilayer_perceptron((tf.slice(M, [0, i], [d, 1])), 
    v_a, weights, biases)], axis=0)

alpha = tf.nn.softmax(tf.reshape(c, [-1]))

v_ns = tf.matmul(M, tf.reshape(alpha, [N, 1]))

layer_3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(weights['W4'], v_ns), biases['b2'])
v_ms = tf.nn.tanh(layer_3)

layer_4 = tf.add(tf.matmul(weights['W5'], v_ms), biases['b3'])
pred = tf.nn.softmax(tf.reshape(layer_4, [-1]))

return pred

M = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
```

I need N to be an integer, but it needs to be equal to the number of columns of the placeholder M, which is not constant across training examples.

Answer (score 1):

*EDIT:*

Seems I didn't understand the question correctly in first instance. I'll leave the original answer because it's related and just in case someone finds it useful.

In any case, if you want to use a dimension of a tensor as the number of iterations in a loop, then the value of the dimension must be known statically (cannot be `None`). You would simply do something like this:

```
for i in range(my_tensor.shape[i_dim].value):
    # loop body...
```

Where `i_dim` is the dimension you want to iterate. Again, if you don't know the size of the tensor dimension, you would need to resort to [`tf.while_loop`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop):

```
def body(dim, i):
    # loop body...
    return dim, i + 1

cond = lambda dim, i: dim > i

tf.while_loop(cond, body, [tf.shape(my_tensor)[i_dim], 0])
```

---

How or whether you can do that at all depends on how much you know about the tensor at the time of looping. If the shape is fully known, you can simply do:

```
for dim in my_tensor.shape.as_list():
    # loop body...
```

Here, `dim` will be regular Python integers for known dimensions. However, if there are unknown dimensions they will be read as `None`. If you don't know the exact dimensions, but you know the rank (i.e. the number of dimensions) of the tensor, you can do something like this:

```
shape = tf.shape(my_tensor)
for i in range(my_tensor.shape.ndims):
    dim = shape[i]
    # loop body...
```

In this case, `dim` will be TensorFlow values holding the tensor dimensions, so you would only be able to use it to compute other tensors, but all the dimensions are guaranteed to be defined.

Finally, if you don't even know the number of dimensions in the tensor, you will not be able to make a regular loop with the shapes. If anything, you could use [`tf.while_loop`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop) to do something like what you need:

```
def body(shape, i):
    dim = shape[i]
    # loop body...
    return shape, i + 1

cond = lambda shape, i: tf.shape(shape)[0] > i

tf.while_loop(cond, body, [tf.shape(my_tensor), 0])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited the question to make it more clear. I will try your code later when I get home.

Comment: I was hoping to use this to get the batch size in a custom loss function used in Keras. However this ended up becoming quite complex since I had downstream functions relying on lists being built up equal to the batch size.